# GridLayout renders on Android 6, but doesn't on other versions (5.x)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

[layout.xml](http://pastebin.com/6U0T3H3u)
[styles.sml](http://pastebin.com/b14eQckw)

This layout renders correctly on emulators running Android 6, but on other versions nothing is displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't want to paste long xml file here.

Comment: You should do. You force users to go somewhere else to see the same long files.